# how to start using flex with java in eclipse, the open source way

Tags: java, apache-flex, eclipse, open-source

I would like to know how to build a flex based flash file and handle it through java but the open-source way. I would like to learn using flex to develop webpages. Is there any way to implement it using eclipse IDE.

Thanks and Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

A few months ago I did the same question to myself, basically what u`re doing in flex/flash is suppose to be the front end, and than you can write the back-end in Java for example.

One easy way it`s comparing :

flex = JSP+javascript
mxml=jsp
actionscript=javascript

Comment: thus there is no way to implement flex framework using java.. Hence if i have to use flex, means i need to learn action script..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "The open source way".

The Flex SDK is open source, and it contains a command line compiler.  I suppose if there is some console plugin to eclipse you could use it to fire off the command line compiler.  You could also use ANT to compile your Flex/ActionScript code.

If you want to use an eclipse IDE for Flex, many people use [Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashbuilder/); which is a commercial product and is not open source.  [FDT](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/) is an alternate eclipse based plugin for Flex, but it is also a commercial product.

Comment: ok.. can i use java and mxml only to run flex application.. i dont know anything about action script.. java is also object oriented so can i use it instead of action script and how..?

Comment: You can accomplish a lot in mxml and Java, but somewhere along the line you're probably going to have to learn some action script. Its very similar to Javascript, so shouldn't be totally unfamiliar.

Comment: You can't use Java as a replacement for ActionScript in a Flex application.  Long term, you'll find that MXML is very limiting w/o any ActionScript.  ActionScript is also object oriented, and to an extend I'd say MXML is too.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think you should have read what Flex actually is before asking on here how do something Flex was not designed for. A good resource to get started is the DevNet: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex.html. As for using Flex in Eclipse, Adobe offers both an Eclipse plugin complete with everything you need to compile Flex, Adobe AIR and Flash applications. They also offer a standalone version of Eclipse with the plugin installed for you. Both are available at http://www.adobe.com/products/flashbuilder/.

Comment: Honestly,I've already been through DevNet. And I am basically looking for the developing flex applications using the open source tools which is my prime requirement to learn about developing Rich Internet Applications. Adobe offers both plugin and complete IDE but not for free... so if u could help me about free tools available i would be much grateful to you...

Comment: Sure. That is a much better question. Open up a command prompt, start up your editor of choice, make a class that extends Sprite, and then compile it using mxmlc (a free binary Adobe provides in the SDK). Now if you are spoiled with Graphical IDEs, you may want to look at Flash Develop. It is the only feature rich IDE that supports Flex & Flash.

Comment: Err... It is the only [free] feature rich IDE....